# A flowchart for concentration bounds

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, randomized-algorithms

When I teach tail bounds, I use the usual progression:

- If your r.v is positive, you can apply Markov's inequality
- If you have independence and **also** bounded variance, you can apply Chebyshev's inequality
- If each independent r.v **also** has all moments bounded, then you can use a Chernoff bound.

After this things get a little less clean. For example

- If your variables have zero mean, then a Bernstein inequality is more convenient
- If all you know is that the combining function is Lipschitz, then there's a generalized McDiarmid-style inequality
- if you have weak dependence then there are Siegel-style bounds, (and if you have negative dependence, then Jansson's inequality might be your friend)

Is there a reference anywhere to a convenient flowchart or decision tree describing how to choose the "right" tail bound, (or even when you have to dive into a sea of Talagrand) ?

*I'm asking partly so that I have a reference, partly so that I can point it to my students, and partly because if I'm sufficiently annoyed and there isn't one, I might try to make one myself.*

Comment: I think the simple answer is no and yes please to anyone who makes one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fan Chung and Linyuan Lu. 
Concentration inequalities and martingale inequalities: a survey
available at
http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.im/1175266369 or at Fan Chung Graham's web page.

Comment: Yes ! this is excellent !  I've read this survey before, but completely forgot about it.

Comment: It's a very nice survey, but I don't see anything like what is requested in the original post: "a convenient flowchart or decision tree describing how to choose the 'right' tail bound" for the random variables you have.

Comment: It's not exactly right, but there are flow charts showing how the different theorems imply each other, which is a start.